# Get a custom UIView subclass to follow a UIControl around

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uicontrol

I've got a subclass of UIControl which represents a slider switch, with a variable 'percent' which stores the current position of the slider, i.e. 0.0 means the slider is on the left, 1.0 means the slider is on the right. I have two images which look like speech bubbles, and when the user clicks the slider I want to display one of these images (they are the same size but look different, designed so one is displayed if percent <= 0.5 and the other one if percent > 0.5) and have the 'tail' of the speech bubble follow the slider (i.e. the frame is set as a function of the percentage).

I have created a custom UIView for the image which changes the image to display via a boolean parameter. I have tried creating a parameter in the UIControl subclass that draws the UIView along with all the other drawing, but I need to draw it outside the UIControl's rect, which can't be done from inside the UIControl's drawRect: method. What would be a good way of managing these two views and making sure the speech bubble always updates when the percentage value of the UIControl changes?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your UIControl should simply be:

- Tall enough to contain the bar and bubble view
- Transparent (so that you can see behind the part of the view where the bubble "slides")

Or am I missing something?

Comment: That would be okay, but I intercept touch events on the UIControl and there's a text field behind where I want the speech bubble to be, so I don't want that area to intercept clicks when there is nothing there. Plus the way the UIControl is built is dependent on the size of its frame as well as the size of its component images so changing the frame size messes it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure the [`continuous` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/continuous) is set to TRUE in your UISlider.

Then, make sure you have an IBAction in place to receive update events from your UISlider.  You can make the connection easily in Interface Builder (built into XCode 4) or you can do it programatically using UIControl's [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) method.

And lastly, inside that IBAction you can now change the frame of your "speech bubble" UIView (make sure to link that up to your parent view controller as a member in your @interface .h file).  Where it appears in relation to the slider is left to you as a homework assignment (cause it's really implementation specific -- or, to put it another way, how it appears is up to each individual app & programmer).

I hope this information helps you out!

Comment: Unfortunately my slider isn't a UISlider subclass, it's a UIControl subclass and only has two states: if the user drops the slider in the middle it'll go to the nearest side. Is there any way I can intercept an event saying the percent value changed?

Comment: so your pseudo-slider only has two states of ("on" and "off")?  it sounds like the percentage values can only be 0% and 100%. Anyways... you can still follow what I wrote in my answer up there... adding a target and an action to your `UIControl` which fires when there is a `UIControlEventValueChanged` event.  This will take care of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers - it turned out the best way to do it was to declare a delegate protocol for my custom UIControl, and assign the speech bubble view as the delegate. Then I made a method that tells the speech bubble to update location (passing in the location) and called that from the UIControl whenever the position of the control updated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplier way is to add to the UIControl a property pointing to the UIView and move it around in the method(s) where you change the control state. Of course to do that you need to create a class like MyCustomControl that extends UIControl.